# Conditional probability with pigs and cherries

Tags: probability

A bowl contains twenty cherries, exactly fifteen of which have had their stones REMOVED. A greedy pig eats five whole cherries without remarking on the presence or absence of stones. Subsequently, a cherry is picked randomly from the remaining fifteen.
(a) What is the probability that this cherry contains a stone?
(b) Given that this cherry contains a stone, what is the probability that the pig consumed at least one stone?

For (a), I thought I would condition on the pig eating 0, 1, ..., 5 stoned cherries, but I'm not sure if it is correct. As for (b), I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative solution method assuming that the pig eats first.

(a) Let $S=$ the number of cherries with $S$tones eaten by the pig. Then $P$($S$ = $i$) = $\dfrac{\binom{5}{i}\binom{15}{5-i}}{\binom{20}{5}}.$

Let $P$($S_6$ | $S = i$) be the probability of selecting a cherry with a $S$tone on the 6th draw given that the pig has eaten $i$ stones out of 5 cherries.

$P(S_6)=\sum_{i=0}^5$ $P$($S_6$ | $S = i$) $P$($S$ = $i$) = $\sum_{i=0}^5$ $\dfrac{\binom{5}{i}\binom{15}{5-i}}{\binom{20}{5}}$ $\dfrac{5-i}{15}=0.25$

(b) Correcting a typo in the answer of @Bananarama: $1-\dfrac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{15}{5}}{\binom{19}{5}}$ = 74.2%.

Comment: For (a), it doesn't matter when the pig ate its cherries. Since we have no information about what was in the cherries the pig ate, we know only that we have one of the original 20 cherries and that 5 of those cherries had stones, so the probability that ours has a stone is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the cherry was picked before and removed and the pig ate after the cherry was removed, then it is clear:

(a) the probability the cherry contains a stone is $\frac{5}{20}=\frac{1}{4}$

(b) if the cherry contains a stone then there are now $19$ cherries in the bowl, $4$ of which contain stones, so the probability the pig eats at least $1$ cherry with stone is $1$ minus the probability the pig eats $5$ cherries without stones, there are 14 cherries with no stone, so that probability is $\dfrac{\binom{14}{5}}{\binom{19}{5}}$. So the probability we are looking for is $1-\dfrac{\binom{14}{5}}{\binom{19}{5}}\approx 83\%$

Comment: I understand (b) but am not clear about (a). Could you expand a bit more?

Comment: Well, we have no information about what the cherries selected by the pig where, so effectively it is the same as just picking a random cherry,